# How to execute 4 shell scripts in parallel, I can't use GNU parallel?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, parallel-processing

I have 4 shell scripts dog.sh, bird.sh, cow.sh and fox.sh. Each of these files execute 4 wgets in parallel using xargs to fork a separate process. Now I want these scripts themselves to be executed in parallel. For some portability reason unknown to me I can't use GNU parallel. IS there a way I can do this with xargs or with any other tool.

Also can I also ask what could the portability reason be?

I'm a total newbie to shell scripting. Sorry if my question seems cryptic.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Without knowing your platform, it is pretty much impossible to determine what the portability reason could be.

Comment: My machine is running ubuntu linux. I know that xargs works on the machine on which the shell script is going to run

Comment: @Suresh But what platform(s) is it to be run on? Without that, people attempting to answer your question will not be able to give solutions that will actually *work* on the target machine.

Comment: I don't know :(. I'm guessing it musbt some flavor of unix that doesn't suport more recent GNU stuff.

Comment: I, too, would like to know the portability reason: GNU Parallel is designed to be extremely portable; as long as you have Perl 5.8 or later you simply copy the file 'parallel' and off you go. http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you there. I'll post a reply as soon as I find out what the reason is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to background all four of the scripts.  You could wrap these with another script "run_parallel.sh" that looks like this:

```
./dog.sh &
./bird.sh &
./cow.sh &
./fox.sh &
```

The ampersand backgrounds the invoked process in a non-blocking fashion causing all 4 to be executed at the same time.

As an example, here's a script called "one_two_three.sh":

```
echo 'One'
sleep 1
echo 'Two'
sleep 1
echo 'Three'
sleep 1
echo 'Done'
```

and a wrapper "wrapper.sh":

```
./one_two_three.sh &
./one_two_three.sh &
./one_two_three.sh &
./one_two_three.sh &
echo 'Four running at once!'
```

Comment: I will also leave an update in a bit as to whether it worked on the target machine

Comment: Worked on target as well :)